# Received parameter from ajax POST empty in controller + passed parameter in firebug MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

I have looked over the net to figure out what my mistake is. All suggestions I found I tried, without any succes. I access the httppost action in my controller but the parameters stays empty.

### AJAX function

```
var dataPost = { 'id': id, 'val': val };
                    debugger;
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: '/Extensions/UpdateJson',
                        data: dataPost ,
                        contentType: 'json',
                        success: function () {
                            alert("succes");
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            alert("error");
                        }
                    });
```

On debug DataPost is populated.

### Controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UpdateJson(string id, string val)
    {
        //do stuff
        return Json(true);
    }
```

The parameters I used in my controller have the same name as in my Ajax function. The format passed is json, I have also tried populating my data with:

```
var dataPost = { 'id': 'id', 'val': 'val' };
```

But this doesn't make any difference. I have also tried to work with a Class, like -->

### Class

```
public class ScheduleData
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string val { get; set; }
}
```

### Controller

```
    public ActionResult UpdateJson(ScheduleData data)
    {//Do something}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The format passed is json

No, not at all. You are not sending any JSON. What you do is

```
data: { 'id': id, 'val': val }
```

But as the documentation clearly explains this is using the `$.param` function which in turn uses `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` encoding.

So get rid of this `contentType: 'json'` property from your $.ajax call.

Or if you really wanna send JSON, then do so:

```
var dataPost = { 'id': id, 'val': val };
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/Extensions/UpdateJson',
    data: JSON.stringify(dataPost),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function () {
        alert("succes");
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("error");
    }
});
```

Things to notice:

- usage of `JSON.stringify(dataPost)` to ensure that you are sending a JSON string to the server
- `contentType: 'application/json'` because that's the correct Content-Type value.

Comment: I just found out myself. I deleted the contenttype before, but it didn't work then probably because of a typo or another error. Thanks